# image is not uploading even though changing in php.ini file

Tags: php, mysql, centos, uploading

I have increased the value of my php.ini file in my VPS then I have restarted my server + restarted service. 
Still it is not upload the more than 5 MB. I am using following code for uploading .  I am uploading images with correct image extension validation.

```
$target_path = "uploads/"; 
$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
    echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). " has been uploaded"; 
}
else{ 
    echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!"; 
}
```

Comment: Post your code, which you have tried?

Comment: The files are uploaded at a temp directory. Are you sure they are not placed there?

Comment: $target_path = "uploads/";
$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']); 

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
    echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). 
    " has been uploaded";
} else{
    echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
}

Comment: did  you put in your form `enctype="multipart/form-data"`?

Comment: Yes i am using enctype="multipart/form-data.. I can upload file upto 5 MB

Comment: Uploads are limited by the timeout and max post size on the webserver as well as php's upload_max_filesize, post_max_size and max_input_time settings - you've provided none of these. Also, your code suggests you've got a GLARING SECURITY HOLE in your website.

Answer (score 1):

There are several options that effect the maximum upload size I believe, have you tried increasing each of;

```
post_max_size = 128M
upload_max_filesize = 128M
memory_limit = 256M
max_input_time = 60
```

---

ssh into your server, type `sudo tail /var/log/apache2/error.log` and post the output into your question.

Comment: do you know what error code/response the server is sending back? have you checked the contents of /var/log/apache2/error.log?

Comment: there no such file in my apache

Comment: there will be an apache error log somewhere, have a look around in /var/log, i dont use centos so cant tell you exactly where it is, but it'll be there somewhere :)

Comment: - - [11/Oct/2012:02:57:52 -0400] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 - "-" "Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS) (internal dummy connection)"
::1 - - [11/Oct/2012:02:57:53 -0400] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 - "-" "Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS) (internal dummy connection)"
::1 - - [11/Oct/2012:02:57:54 -0400] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 - "-" "Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS) (internal dummy connection)"
::1 - - [11/Oct/2012:02:57:55 -0400] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 - "-"

Comment: youre gonna have to go higher than that, try `nano /path/to/error.log` and have a look around. there might be no errors, depending on the issue, i don't know if php would actually log an error, but it seems likely.

Answer (score 0):

Please try with increase `max_execution_time` in `php.ini` configuration file